# divide counts in one column where a condition is met

Tags: count, where-clause, division

I am trying to determine the on time delivery rate of orders:

The column of interest is on time delivery orders, which contains a field of 0 (not on time) or 1 ( on time).  How can I calculate in sql the on time rate for each person?  Basically count the number of 0 / over total count(0's & 1's) for each person?  Same thing for on time ( count 1/total count (0's & 1's)?

Heres a data example:

```
Week  Delivery on time  Person
1         0              sARAH
1         0              sARAH
1         1              sARAH
2         1              vIC
2         0              Vic
```

Comment: Please add the _exact_ output you want here.  If your current sample data does not convey what you need, then expand the sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You may aggregate by person, and then take the average of the on time statistic:

```sql
SELECT Person, AVG(1.0*DeliveryOnTime) AS OnTime,
               AVG(1.0 - DeliveryOnTime) AS NotOnTime
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Person;
```

### Demo

The demo given is for SQL Server, and the above syntax might have to change slightly depending on your actual database, which you did not reveal to us.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  This didnt give the output I was expecting.   Just 0's and 1's... I want it to count the # of )'s and divide by the total count of 0's and 1's.  So for the example for sarah we have 3 entries, 2 zero's and 1 one.  I would expect to see on time rate of 1/3 = .33.  How can I get this rate for each person for each week?

Comment: Oh...your sample data did not make it clear you want per person, per week.  If so, then just change the query to use `GROUP BY Week, Person`, and then add `Week` to the select clause.

Comment: Tried that... It still did not give me a rate of .33 ( as outlined in the example above).  What am I not capturing?